# How to set WMI property values?

Tags: windows, wmi, autoit, wmi-query

I want to modify some properties on a VM. I'm using AutoIt to hide them where I can. Seems some of these are read only under [`Win32_ComputerSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx), but it seems possible to set them using PowerShell.

```
$objWMIService = ObjGet ("winmgmts:\\" & $com & "\root\CIMV2")
$colItems = $objWMIService.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor", "WQL", 0x30)
```

I can read the property values in a loop but I'm not sure if it's possible to write my own values back in. Is this doable using AutoIt?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about which values you are trying to change but you can check with

```
Set-WmiInstance
```